# Replying to missed message on mailing list

Tags: email, mailing-list

I missed a message on a sourceware mailing list from yesterday. I.e. I only subscribed to the list today and found a message regarding the same problem I was having that was posted yesterday (through the search function).

Is there any way I can reply to that message, as if I had been subscribed to the mailing list yesterday?

I know there is an In-Reply-To header field for e-mails, but I think I need some sort of message id to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the mailing list, there may be a web interface that lets you reply to a message (e.g. gmane allows this).

If not, there may be a web interface to view the message's ID, which you can then use in the In-Reply-To header.

If not, I doubt there's a way to do what you want.